# Generating subplots of heatmaps in Julia-lang

Tags: matplotlib, julia, heatmap

I am trying to produce a figure/plot with more than a single heatmap (matrix with color shading according to the cell value). At the moment `using Plots;
pyplot()` and `heatmap(mat)` is enough to produce a heatmap.

It is not clear to me how to  produce a single figure with more though. After looking at this page [example subplots](https://juliaplots.github.io/examples/pyplot/#subplots) for how to use the layout, and then the [example histogram](https://juliaplots.github.io/examples/pyplot/#heatmap-categorical-axes-and-aspect_ratio), I cannot seem to produce working examples for the two together.

The question is how to produce a figure with two different matrices displayed via heatmap or some other function to do the same?

(as an extra side, could you also explain the context of the 'using' statement and how it relates to the 'backend'?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a Vector of heatmaps, then plot those

```
using Plots
hms = [heatmap(randn(10,10)) for i in 1:16];
plot(hms..., layout = (4,4), colorbar = false)
```

The `using` statement calls the `Plots` library. The "backend" is another package, loaded by Plots, that does the actual plotting. Plots itself has no plotting capabilities - it translates the plot call to a plot call for the backend package.

Explanation of the code above:
Plotting with Plots is a two-step process. 1: `plot` generates a `Plot` object with all the information for the plot; 2: when a `Plot` object is returned to the console, it automatically calls julia´s `display` function, which then generates the plot. But you can do other things with the `Plot` object first, like put it in an array.

The `heatmap` call is a short form of `plot(randn(10,10), seriestype = :heatmap)`, so it just creates a Plot object. 16 Plot objects are stored in the vector.

Passing a number of Plot objects to `plot` creates a new, larger Plot, with each of the incoming `Plot` objects as subplots. The splat operator `...` simply passes each element of the `Array{Plot}` to `plot` as an individual argument.

[image]

Comment: Great answer, and works well, can you tell me what is the reason for the `plot(hms...` what do the triple periods do because without them, it produces errors.

Comment: `plot` accepts a variable number of arguments - in fact any number of arguments if the argument is of type `Plot` (the result of calling `plot` on something else), in which case each `Plot` oblect will constitute a subplot. The three dots "splats" the array over the argument list - i.e. `a = [1,2,3]; foo(a...)` is the same as `foo(1,2,3)`. Surprisingly often convenient.

Comment: I've added some info on the answer.

Comment: Remark in passing: `aspect_ratio = :equal` doesn't have great defaults, you also need to set `grid=false` and reset the axes limits, if you want something both square and pretty.